# Reading a value of a short from file data

Tags: c

I have a file (pointed to by *data) which begins with a struct.

I would like to get to the value of nsectionheaders in memory so that I can use it.

I've tried this, but it's returning a strangely large negative value. How do I get it to return the right value?

```
   void read_file_header(void *data) {

    int offset = (sizeof(char) * 16) + (sizeof(int) * 4) + sizeof(int) + (sizeof(short) * 6);
    char *pointer = (char *) data + offset;

    short num_sec_headers = 0;
    memcpy(&num_sec_headers, &pointer, sizeof(short));
    printf("The number of headers is %d\n", num_sec_headers);

   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
memcpy(&num_sec_headers, &pointer, sizeof(short));
```

is incorrect. You are taking the address of the pointer, instead of just using pointer:

```
memcpy(&num_sec_headers, pointer, sizeof(short));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a secure `offsetof` in the standard (include `stddef.h`):

```
   void read_file_header(void *data) {
       int offset = offsetof(ElfFileHeader, nsectionheaders);
       short num_sec_headers;

       memcpy(&num_sec_headers, (char *)data + offset, sizeof(short));
       printf("The number of headers is %d\n", num_sec_headers);
   }
```

Comment: It needs to be `memcpy`. `data` may not be correctly aligned (if it is from a `char` buffer).

Comment: @user694733, true, it comes from a file, edited thanks